# Can't add kits and can't choose Qt version in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I tried to work with Qt Creator, but when I start a new project, I have to create a new kit. But in the kit menu, I can't choose a Qt version nor a debugger, my only option is 'none'. It doesn't work for any device type.

I have the option to add a Qt version though, but which folder, file or executable I have to open?

Comment: To the downvoters: The question is completely clear, and it describes a problem commonly faced by novices to Qt Creator.

Comment: Which OS are you using and what compiler and Qt version do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for you the easiest to do is to do a brand new installation. Install qtversion 5.5 and it will automatically install qtcreator and configure the settings correctly.

Follow the following links for each platform,

Linux : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html

Windows: use the installer at http://www.qt.io/download/

Comment: I did not use Qt since then, but now that i re-read this post i tried again and somehow it worked? I don't have any clue why, i don't think i changed anything about Qt, but im glad its working now and i don't have to reinstall, thanks a lot for your answer anyways ;) i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->Options->Build and run->Qt Versions->Add

[As this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4wxu.png)

Navigate through your Qt installation folder as shown in link and go to bin folder to find qmake, then Select and apply.

Under Kits Tab:
Select your kit
Go to Qt Version, where Added Qt version will be reflected from drop down list.
Select, apply and Press Ok.

Comment: I don't have a tab called "Qt Versions".

Comment: I have the tab called "Qt Versions" right next to the "Kits" tab. I cannot find any qt version, from the screenshot and from the header "Select qmake executable", it should be called "qmake", and `qmake --version` gives `qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory`. Seems as if there is no qt installed at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You have to *add* a Qt version and a debugger first, then click `Apply`, then you can create a kit that uses that version.